# How to Increase Query Speed of Large Tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have 2 tables I am using in a query: tableA and tableB. TableA has a row count of 80568353, and tableB is at 101806780. They both share the same 10 columns (tableB has an additional 4 columns) including p_id. My goal is to have a query that creates a new table from tableA where the p_id does not match the p_id in tableB. Here's my query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.tableC AS
    SELECT * FROM my_schema.tableA
    WHERE p_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT p_id::int FROM my_schema.tableB)
```

This ran overnight and never completed. I went and ran `EXPLAIN` to see why. Here' is the results:

```
 Gather  (cost=20252382.21..3330358576969.77 rows=40283932 width=89)
   Workers Planned: 7
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tableA  (cost=20251382.21..3330354547576.57 rows=5754847 width=89)
    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
    SubPlan 1
      ->  Materialize  (cost=20251382.21..20814813.52 rows=6107669 width=8)
            ->  Unique  (cost=20251382.21..20760416.17 rows=6107669 width=8)
                  ->  Sort  (cost=20251382.21..20505899.19 rows=101806792 width=8)
                        Sort Key: tableB.p_id
                        ->  Seq Scan on tableB  (cost=0.00..5079937.92 rows=101806792 width=8)
```

I'm new to PostgreSQL, but cost=20251382.21..3330354547576.57 seems extraordinarily high. I tried to go back and run the following to create an index to speed things up:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS a_p_int_idx ON my_schema.tableA (CAST(p_id as int));
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS b_p_int_idx ON my_schema.tableB (CAST(p_id as int));
```

This didn't seem to help. I also ran `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both tables. No improvement. What am I doing wrong here; is there any way to increase the speed and get this to run Or an alternative method of achieving my goal? Note: tableA's p_id is an int and tableB's p_id is double precision. Would that affect it?

UPDATE: I was not able to get `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to complete but I was able to run `EXPLAIN VERBOSE`

```
Gather  (cost=20506959.93..3330368701110.81 rows=40283932 width=89)
Output: tableA.geoid, tableA.p_id, tableA.land_use_t, tableA.prop_ind_t, tableA.story_nbr, tableA.bld_units, tableA.censuspop, tableA.hu_pop, tableA.point_x, tableA.point_y
Workers Planned: 7
->  Parallel Seq Scan on my_schema.tableA  (cost=20505959.93..3330364671717.61 rows=5754847 width=89)
    Output: tableA.geoid, tableAs.p_id, tableA.land_use_t, tableA.prop_ind_t, tableA.story_nbr, tableA.bld_units, tableA.censuspop, tableA.hu_pop, tableA.point_x, tableA.point_y
    Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
    SubPlan 1
      ->  Materialize  (cost=20505959.93..21069392.95 rows=6107669 width=4)
            Output: ((tableB.p_id)::integer)
            ->  Unique  (cost=20505959.93..21014995.61 rows=6107669 width=4)
                  Output: ((tableB.p_id)::integer)
                  ->  Sort  (cost=20505959.93..20760477.77 rows=101807136 width=4)
                        Output: ((tableB.p_id)::integer)
                        Sort Key: ((tableB.p_id)::integer)
                        ->  Seq Scan on my_schema.tableB  (cost=0.00..5334459.20 rows=101807136 width=4)
                              Output: (tableB.p_id)::integer
```

I also tried

```
EXPLAIN VERBOSE
SELECT * FROM my_schema.tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT p_id FROM 
my_schema.tableB 
WHERE p_id::int = a.p_id)
```

to test the `NOT EXISTS` suggestions but the cost came out the same (no real improvement).

Comment: What is the type of `p_id`, and why cast it to `int` when creating the indexes? This is just a shot in the dark, but you may also need to cast it when you query, for example, `where cast(pid as int) not int (select distinct cast(pid as int) from tableB`).

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) ? Without it, it's impossible to see where the time is spend.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is not needed.

Comment: Note: tableA's p_id is an int and tableB's p_id is double precision. Would that affect it? (Added to question)

Comment: By the way, NOT EXISTS() is most likely faster than the NOT IN() construction you're using right now.

Comment: Running EXPLAIN ANALYZE now; will put in original question.

Comment: If you would have same columns in selects from both tables, you could try to use EXCEPT clausule like:
    CREATE TABLE my_schema.tableC AS
    SELECT p_id  FROM my_schema.tableA
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT p_id::int FROM my_schema.tableB

Comment: Please include the table definitions.

Comment: I updated my question with the suggestions. I could never get `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to complete (its still running since the comment was posted). I did get `VERBOSE` to run and added it. I also tried using the `NOT EXISTS` suggestion but found it did not give me any real improvements.

Comment: Please add the plan for the NOT EXISTS variant. The cost isn't really that interesting

Answer (score 2):

In many Databases the command `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` gets bad performance, because you can write this query using the `left join` and you will get very very high performance. For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.tableA aa 
left join my_schema.tableB bb on aa.p_id = bb.p_id 
WHERE 
    bb.id is null --here you must use one of the not null field of tableB (for example primary key of tableB)
```

And you must create a normal `btree index` for `p_id` fields in both tables.